# Java regex match not working as expected

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I am having a String:

```
String str = "sourceType=Match, msg=Event yyuyu, test 1, usrPicture=null, friendCount=0";
```

Now I am writing a regex expression to replace value for "msg" with "...." 
My regex looks like:

```
str.replaceAll("(\\smsg=)(.+?)(,)", "$1...$3");
```

As per my above regex it matches till:

```
msg=Event yyuyu,
```

but I want it to match till:

```
msg=Event yyuyu, test 1,
```

Basically It should match till last "," (By this I mean it should match till last "," for value of key "msg"). I tried to put some regex after (,). But it's not working. Any help on this will be really appreciated.

Comment: Check [`msg=(.*?),\s*\S+=`](https://regex101.com/r/vtevwk/1)

Comment: Because I want the result like:   msg=....

Comment: @Tushar as per your regex it matches till: msg=Event yyuyu, test 1, usrPicture=

Comment: You need to extract _Group 1_ using `$1` or `\1`.

Comment: is `usrPicture` always the next attribute after `msg`?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, you are saying to match as minimum characters as possible by adding `?` in `(.+?)`. Try removing it.

```
 str.replaceAll("(\\smsg=)(.+)(,)", "$1...$3");
```

Moreover, you mentioned you want to match till last `,` so it should match till

```
msg=Event yyuyu, test 1, usrPicture=null,
```

not till

```
msg=Event yyuyu, test 1,
```

as you specified in your question.

See this https://regex101.com/r/BCNsTt/1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match till the next attribute `(usrPicture)` as in your example, not as in your question, then you can try the following regex

`(\smsg=)(.+?)(,)(\s\w+=)`

Replace with `$1...$3$4`

Output:

`sourceType=Match, msg=..., usrPicture=null, friendCount=0`

Demo can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/wA6jTb/1)